# unexpected behaviour of WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am learning WPF and I programmed one little example which uses the concept of "Bindings". But the program behaves differently than I would expect.

I have Person class which has two properties : FirstName and LastName. 
This class implements INotifyPropertyChanged interface therefore I can use it for binding.

```
 class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string firstName;
    private string lastName;

    public string FirstName
    {
        get {  return firstName; }
        set { NotifyPropertyChanged("FirstName"); firstName = value; }
    }

    public string LastName
    {
        get { return lastName; }
        set { NotifyPropertyChanged("LastName"); lastName = value; }
    }

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

}
```

Then I have some XAML code.

```
<Window x:Class="BughouseClient.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Name="stackPanel">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=FirstName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
        </TextBox>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=LastName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBox>
        <Button Click="Fill">
            Click
        </Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

MainClass code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    Person person;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        person = new Person();
        person.FirstName = "Bruce";
        person.LastName = "Lee";
        stackPanel.DataContext = person;
    }

    void Fill(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        person.FirstName = "John";
        person.LastName = "Jones";     
    }
}
```

I was expecting that when I hit the Click button, FirstName and LastName property will change and I will see them in the textboxes immediately.
But I have to click TWICE to see the change in the textboxes.
Pls, does anybody know why?

..
I found out, when I change MainClass code to this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    Person person;
    int i = 1;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        person = new Person();
        person.FirstName = "Bruce";
        person.LastName = "Lee";
        stackPanel.DataContext = person;
    }

    void Fill(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (i == 1)
        {
            person.FirstName = "John";
            person.LastName = "Jones";
            i++;
        }
        if (i == 2)
        {
            person.FirstName = "Jim";
            person.LastName = "Parker";
        }
    }
}
```

It "magically" works! I can see John Jones in the textboxes immediately. But I cant explain why. Any help would be really appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: In the setter "NotifyPropertyChanged" goes after setting the value

Comment: Thank you for your help! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Notification needs to happen after you have updated your backing field.

this:

```
set { NotifyPropertyChanged("FirstName"); firstName = value; }
```

Should be:

```
set { firstName = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("FirstName");  }
```

Binding trigger happens when you call NotifyPropertyChanged, as such if you have that first, then your field doesn't get updated when binding is triggered, and you end up having the old value still showing up.

Comment: Thank you, didnt notice that.. But I still cant explain, why it "worked" in the second example. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Yes, it works second time because during your second invocation the field had the value sitting there from prior change. You can test this case by typing a new value second time, you will see that it falls back to the last update.

Comment: @DavidŽigo Because in the second example when you press the button the properties get changed twice.  First they get changed to John Jones, you increment i, and then the next if statement is entered and the properties are then changed to Jim Parker.

Comment: Aaah now I understand everything :-)) Thank you very much guys!!

Answer (score 0):

A good practice is to check for equality first to avoid firing NotifyPropertyChanged

```
set 
{ 
    if (firstName == value) return;
    firstName = value; 
    NotifyPropertyChanged("FirstName");  
}
```

Comment: Thank you for advice. I would vote you up, but I cant yet, Im novice here :)